Successor of pam_tally2
I am using pam_tally2 for some time to count failed logins.
/etc/pam.d/common-auth
auth    optional      pam_tally2.so onerr=succeed audit debug

I had integrated it into pam and when I needed the count I called pam_tally2 on the commandline and it gave me the output.
But it is gone in Debian 12 - or maybe even since Debian 11.
Is there any other tool that is that easy to use?
I need the counter not in a logfile or after login - I need by request.
And I only want to count it - no lockout of users etc. required.
EDIT
I had a look at faillock - but as far I understood it is for primaryfor locking users out.
And I have no idea how it is possible to make faillog do its job.
